How to fix 500 (Internal Server Error) in filezilla localhost (ASP.NET MVC)
I have uploaded new build (.dll file) in FileZilla,
the previous one was working perfectly, after the new build it is throwing 500 (Internal Server Error).
Project Works fine in my local (Visual studio localhost).
But the Index View is Working fine others are not loading. And instead of expected view it is returning some other view.
What might be the cause of this?
    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Dashboard( string keyword, string status, string category, int? page)
        {
            eCertificateModel obj = new eCertificateModel();
            obj.obj2 = new pageFilterModel();


            obj.obj2.keyword = keyword;
            obj.obj2.status = status;
            obj.obj2.categoryId = category;

            try
            {
                
                int pageSize = 10;
                int pageIndex = 1;
                pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;
                obj.pagedList = getData(obj).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            return View(obj);
        }
 

i tried to return the Exception But it is Returning Some other View,

Without knowing what exception is thrown, it's quite hard to say anything ...

When you run the VIsual Studio debugger what error does it show?

Visual Studio debugger is not throwing any errors
